# How can I delete a pending pull request?

Tags: git, github

I have created a pull request.
Later I realized I need to overwrite that pull request with an updated commit.
But Github does not allow me to do another pull request because of the first pending one.
Can I delete the previous pull request?

Answer (score 3):

If you update the branch that the pull request is based off of, GitHub will automatically update the pull request to match the branch. You don't have to recreate it. Just push a new version of the branch.

If you rewrote history (e.g. `commit --amend` or `rebase`), you'll need to use the `--force` flag when pushing the replacement commit(s).